# Find $\sqrt{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{\lfloor 1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor}{\sqrt{2}-\cos|x|+\sin|x|}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\sqrt{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{\lfloor 1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor}{\sqrt{2}-\cos\left\vert x\right\vert+\sin\left\vert x\right\vert}\rm{d}x$$

For $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, $\lfloor 1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor=0$

For $x\in\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$, $\lfloor 1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor=1$

Using the property $$\int_a^bf(x)\rm{d}x=\int_a^cf(x)\rm{d}x+\int_c^bf(x)\rm{d}x$$
$$\sqrt{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{\lfloor 1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor}{\sqrt{2}-\cos\left\vert x\right\vert+\sin\left\vert x\right\vert}\rm{d}x=\sqrt{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\cos x+\sin x}\rm{d}x$$

$$=\sqrt{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\rm{d}x=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\rm{d}x$$
I substituted $x-\frac{\pi}{4}=t$ and then $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-u$ to get
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\cos u}\rm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\rm{d}x$$

But answer given is $\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sqrt{2}+\frac{3\pi}{4}$. I wont get logarithm in my answer.

Comment: I didnt get your first step $ln(-1)\neq 0$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I have edited the post

Comment: at $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\lfloor 1+\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor = 2$ and $\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \approx 0$ so anyway.